# Adding several buttons to messagebox

Tags: c#-4.0

I will be grateful for your answer. How i am adding buttons to the messagebox?  To be clearly, I have a button, when i press on the Save button i get a messagebox with this text: "Please..." and both those buttons, Cancel and Proceed.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill all..."); // I like to add to this messagebox buttons

        {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=VirtualSalesFair;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Insert into Empty value('" + textBox1.Text + "'," + textBox2.Text + ",'" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" +textBox9.Text +"',"+textBox10.Text +");", con);
        int o=sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show(o+ ":Record has been inserted");
        con.Close();            
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wont to use standard messages like Yes/No, Cancel, etc... ([see list here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons.aspx)), you can simpy create a new windows forms, that will look like message box. Add custom buttons, the text you like and then you just make it to show:

```
NewForm customMessageBox = new NewForm();
customMesageBox.Show(this);
```

thats it.
Do not forget to put this.Close() in the buttons to close the form after the desired action is performed.